# Pentaho How to disable cache?

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-design-studio

My problem is when i add some additional jar file into some lib directory of Pentaho Enterprise Edition then I have to restart server to reflect changes.
Is there any way so that i can see my changes by avoiding re-start of server?
I think it maintains some cache, if we disable it there will be no need to restart it, but i dont know how to disable it.

Comment: DI server or BI Server?

Comment: Yes, i need for BI server.

Comment: You may have a clue @ https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/161053-Disabling-cache-for-Pentaho/